# Upgrading themes never works

Tags: updates

I have a Wordpress installation running on my own server at home, serving a domain name I bought. It's running on Debian Linux, currently installed under `/usr/share/wordpress`.

When I'm in the Admin panel, I see notifications for updates to the themes or plug-ins. So, I SSH into my server, turn on the FTP daemon, then start the update. Below is an example output:

```
Downloading install package from http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/akismet.3.0.0.zip…
Unpacking the package…
Installing the plugin…
Could not create directory. /var/lib/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/akismet/
Plugin install failed.
```

This is starting to get a little annoying. The directory exists, and the user that the FTP is running on (www-data) has write access to the folder. Why can the Updater not remove the old plug in, then install the new one?

---

[Meta Discussion](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/troubleshooting-upgrade-issues-on-topic) about being on or off topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Could not create directory` is still a permissions error; have you checked [Changing File Permissions « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)? Are wp-content, themes and plugins 755?

> Any file that needs write access from WordPress should be owned or
>   group-owned by the user account used by the WordPress (which may be
>   different than the server account). For example, you may have a user
>   account that lets you FTP files back and forth to your server, but
>   your server itself may run using a separate user, in a separate
>   usergroup, such as dhapache or nobody. If WordPress is running as the
>   FTP account, that account needs to have write access, i.e., be the
>   owner of the files, or belong to a group that has write access. In the
>   latter case, that would mean permissions are set more permissively
>   than default (for example, 775 rather than 755 for folders, and 664
>   instead of 644).

Comment: All permissions in `/usr/share/wordpress/wp-content` and /var/lib/wordpress/wp-content` (as well as the `wp-content/` directories) have 755 permissions, as expected. The group owners are `www-data`, which is what my web server is running under

Comment: Sounds like you need to take a look at chmod in the shell and check the owners/groups. Check http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26045/how-do-i-get-the-right-permissions-for-wordpress-running-apache-on-debian